# Explain how this event works

Tags: c#, events, methods, delegates

I'm learning C and C#, this question is for C#. What does this mean? This question was closed but I don't see why, it was confusing for me that the code I asked about, wrote Console.WriteLine("Event fired!"); to the console, if it was null. I didn't understand what it ment that it fired. Did the event do something?

```
 if (ChangeNum != null)
 {
    ChangeNum();
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Event fired!");
 }
```

If changeNum is not null it just says it fired, where does it fire, why does it fire? There is no subscription of the event. What does this do ChangeNum();?

Here is the code:

```
public class EventTest
{
   private int value;

   public delegate void NumManipulationHandler();

   public event NumManipulationHandler ChangeNum;

   protected virtual void OnNumChanged()
   {
      if (ChangeNum != null)
      {
         ChangeNum();
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Event fired!");
      }
   }
   public EventTest(int n )
   {
      SetValue(n);
   }
   public void SetValue(int n)
   {
      if (value != n)
      {
         value = n;
         OnNumChanged();
      }
   }
 }

 public class MainClass
 {
    public static void Main()
    {
       EventTest e = new EventTest(5);
       e.SetValue(7);
       e.SetValue(11);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
 }
```

This code is from this tutorial found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_events.htm)

Comment: The code `if (ChangeNum != null)
     {
        ChangeNum(); }` is not really thread safe. The underlying field will be read twice. It might be different from `null` when the `if` condition is evaluated, but then another thread might unsubscribe from the event. Then when you come to the invoke `ChangeNum();` a null reference exception could arise. Therefore as far as I know it is recommended to copy the underlying field to a local variable, as in `var currentHandler = ChangeNum; if (currentHandler != null) { currentHandler(); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it checks `if any delegate is hooked to an event` (**null if no delegate is hooked to it**).

In case `yes` simply `raise the event` so that delegate hook to that events gets executed. Otherwise, simply write on Console if not delegate is hooked to an event.

Posted code output will be -

```
Event fired!
Event fired!
Event fired!
```

But if you hook to that event and provide a delegate like below -

```
EventTest e = new EventTest(5);
e.ChangeNum += Handler;

private void Handler()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Event handled!");
}
```

output will be -

```
Event fired!
Event handled!
Event handled!
```

Since you have hooked onto that event, it is not null any more. It will raise an event which will simply invoke method `Handler()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `OnNumChanged` method fires the `ChangeNum` event. An event in C# is implementing using delegates.

The `if(ChangeNum != null)` part is a standard pattern to allow the code to do nothing (or in your case print "Event fired!") if there are no subscribers to your event. If you did not do this null check, the `ChangeNum()` call would result in a null reference exception.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Thanks, I removed it, since I realize I do not know how events are implemented on the low level. Conceptually, I like to regard them as multicast delegate properties though.

Answer (score 2):

`ChangeNum` is a event for the `EventTest`, events are subscription that you often listen to, and is raised when changes occur in state of the associated object.

Now your code

```
if (ChangeNum != null)
 {
    ChangeNum();
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Event fired!");
 }
```

`if` is checking if any subscription is already made for the event, if any methods is listening for it, it will let that method know that object's state was changed

`else` part show message on the console if no methods are subscribed for the event!

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - yes, i agree! i was just providing a simple answer!